# Flutter layouts the elements of the Row correctly but gives RangeError on console?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

i have a widget which returns 2 possible layouts as you can see the numerations in the screenshot, i don't get any errors on the console  for scenarios where it transforms from 1 -> 2, 1->1 , 2->2.

But, when it goes from 2->1 ,

i get couple of (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..x : y) errors. ( I only get this where AnswerBar goes from layout 2 to layout 1 )

It always works correctly and i never get any incorrect layout or a error indicating banner on the phone but it's annoying to get this error on the debug console.How can i solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please also add the AnswerBarBubble's widget code?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `LayoutBuilder`, which should be treated how you would a function handler for the purpose of reading a provider because it's using a different context than your parent component where you are reading the `answerLengthProvider`.

The fix is to use `context.read` within the `LayoutBuilder` instead of `useProvider` outside of it.

```dart
class AnswerBar extends HookWidget {
  const AnswerBar() : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('AnswerBar built.');
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
      final _answerLength = context.read(answerLengthProvider);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex , this solution did not give any different result but at least i am aware of my antipattern usage from now on. Also, i shared the solution below.

Comment: Really? I set up an example locally and this fixed it for me.

Comment: We are not obliged to use context.read actually , we can wrap the LayoutBuilder with consumer which will also allow us to watch the provider instead of being limited to reading.

Comment: But i am not sure if  Consumer will add an overhead in the matter of performance...

Comment: Consumer is a very performant mechanism as it only rebuilds its children rather than the entire widget.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is : using keys. ( I used for AnswerBar )

Simply , if you find yourself adding , removing or reordering collection of widgets of the same type that hold some state ( which is my case) , key is the solution.

I found the solution from these Flutter official resources :

video format : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

article format : https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d

Comment: Ah, yes. This is something I meant to mention to you as well. All your widgets should have the default Key parameter, even when you aren't using them as well.